# Google font just will not work

Tags: css, html, font-face, google-font-api, embedded-fonts

I have followed the instructions on the google fonts website over an over and my webpage displays as it should on MY laptop, however, the fonts 'FJALLA ONE' does not load on any other computer or device.

Am I doing something wrong? Can I store the fonts in a folder and link them like a css file?

Here is my html - part 1:

```
head>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

part 2:

```
<div class="box">
        <h1 class="animated bounceInDown">SHEREE WALKER </h1> </div>
```

My CSS

```
.box h1 {
    font-family:'FjallaOne', sans-serif;    !important;
    font-size:45px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    padding-top: 10%; }
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be amazing. I'm at my wits end.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. Are you saying it works on some computers? How about the other font you are using? Is it displaying on all the computers?

Comment: Use google fonts in React.js? solution provided already here >>https://stackoverflow.com/a/47733243/8625811

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem probably exists in this piece of code:

```
font-family:'FjallaOne', sans-serif;    !important;
```

it should be

```
font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif !important;
```

OR

```
font-family:'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
```

If that still does not fix it try removing `, sans-serif`

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work. I really don't know what is going on.

Comment: @ShereeWalker Please review the link Mikey has posted to the jsfiddle and make sure yours looks similar to his example. It could be the color that makes it seem like it is not working. If that still does not work, can you provide a link to where this webpage is located?

Comment: Actually I just checked the google link and in your font family you need a space so it would look like this:

`font-family: 'Fjalla One';`

Comment: @Zachary1748 Nice catch, I was in auto mode so I looked up the font myself and copy pasted it from there :)...and yes it does not work when you make it one word. Although OP mentions that it works on a different laptop. I am confused :/

Comment: @Mikey - I uninstalled the font from my laptop and sure enough it stopped displaying correctly, which explains that. It's all working good now though. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ShereeWalker No problem. Good luck and don't stress :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not with your code. It is fine. I would remove the `!important` though, it's not necessary and the syntax is also not correct, but the code will still work even with wrong syntax.

What your real problem is: the text is white so you will never see it on a white background. You can see it here working with red text-> http://jsfiddle.net/sxntrvrj/1/

```
h1 {
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif; 
    font-size:45px;
    text-align:center;
    color:red;
    padding-top: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Even before the 'important' it did not work.
I've just uploaded my site (unfinished) to look at - when I view it on any other computer the main header falls apart. It only works on my laptop where I have the fonts installed.

Comment: You know that you don't have to install anything, google fonts loads from a  remote server. It works fine on my pc. I will post a screen image, although sheree walker is overlapping each other.

Comment: @ShereeWalker try clearing your browser cache by pressing Ctlr + Shift + R 

OR 

Ctrl + F5

Comment: The words overlap because that is not FJALLA ONE displaying. Took me ages to realise

Comment: I swapped colours back and forth when checking on other computers. New colour = new file, not cached.

Comment: @ShereeWalker Your problem is mentioned in the other answer and I have given you a correct sample to work with! You need to have space between Fjalla and One.

Comment: @ShereeWalker I have noticed in your stylesheet there is a missing comma and a space therefore it is not reading correctly make sure it looks like this: `font-family: "Fjalla One", sans-serif;`. Then remove the box fixed width and this will fix the overlapping issue.

Comment: @Zachary1748 This is funny though. It is really only the space just tested it on OP's website. Changed the css in the console and it did not overlap anymore. LOL

Comment: @Mikey is right lol, the overlapping is caused from the missing space in the font

Comment: Hoorah! Now it works! I have no idea why I had a space in there. 
I am a tad embarrassed though - I have been working on that issue for a good couple of days