# How to use Google fonts in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-font-api

I had built a website with *React.js* and *webpack*.

I want to use *Google fonts* in the webpage, so I put the link in the  section.

### [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Bungee+Inline?selection.family=Bungee%20Inline)

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Inline" rel="stylesheet">
```

#### And set CSS

```
body{
    font-family: 'Bungee Inline', cursive;
}
```

However, it does not work.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You put the `<link>` into the page header, not into your react app, correct? Do you specify the `font-family` anywhere else in your stylesheet or on your elements directly?

Comment: Are you using https, and do you have a security policy in place?

Comment: Actually, I do know what is the correct method of importing Google Fonts.
I think I need a simple example.
Can you help me...

Comment: what does your markdown look like? are you defining other styles that might overwrite that more generic one?

Comment: I had solved this problem.....
The method I tried before was wrong. This is the correct method.
[Using Google Fonts locally (in hjs-webpack and React)](http://jimthedev.com/2016/07/28/using-google-fonts-in-webpack-and-react/)
However, there are still some error in the webpack process. Those two line code should be writed in **webpack.config.js** file.
`{ test: /(\.css$)/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'] }, { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }`

Comment: Read this [simple tutorial](https://scotch.io/@micwanyoike/how-to-add-fonts-to-a-react-project) -  will help anybody

Answer (score 173):

In some sort of main or first loading CSS file, just do:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:regular,bold,italic&subset=latin,latin-ext');
```

You don't need to wrap in any sort of @font-face, etc. the response you get back from Google's API is ready to go and lets you use font families like normal.

Then in your main React app JavaScript, at the top put something like:

```
import './assets/css/fonts.css';
```

What I did actually was made an `app.css` that imported a `fonts.css` with a few font imports. Simply for organization (now I know where all my fonts are). The important thing to remember is that you import the fonts first.

Keep in mind that any component you import to your React app should be imported after the style import. Especially if those components also import their own styles. This way you can be sure of the ordering of styles. This is why it's best to import fonts at the top of your main file (don't forget to check your final bundled CSS file to double check if you're having trouble).

There's a few options you can pass the Google Font API to be more efficient when loading fonts, etc. See official documentation: [Get Started with the Google Fonts API](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started)

Edit, note: If you are dealing with an "offline" application, then you may indeed need to download the fonts and load through Webpack.

Comment: can you please explain why the way of using link in html head doesn't work ?

Comment: @doobean It will work

Answer (score 125):

**Google fonts in React.js?**

Open your stylesheet i.e, app.css, style.css (what name you have), it doesn't matter, just open stylesheet and paste this code

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans');
```

and don't forget to change URL of your font that you want, else working fine

and use this as :

```
body {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', cursive;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to load the fonts with JS? I mean for perfomance reasons.

Comment: can you please explain why the way of using link in html head doesn't work ?

Comment: Very stupid but I found my custom fonts were not working because I had mistyped as follows:

    .body {
        font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    }

Of course that extra `.` in front of the `body` meant that it was a CSS class named `body` and not applying the font family site-wide. *face-palm.

Answer (score 33):

If you are using Create React App environment simply add @import rule to **index.css** as such:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton');
```

Import **index.css** in your main React app:

```
import './index.css'
```

React gives you a choice of Inline styling, CSS Modules or Styled Components in order to apply CSS:

```
font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 21):

Here are two different ways you can adds fonts to your react app.

### Adding local fonts

1. Create a new folder called `fonts` in your `src` folder.
2. Download the google fonts locally and place them inside the `fonts` folder.
3. Open your `index.css` file and include the font by referencing the path.

```js
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Rajdhani';
  src: local('Rajdhani'), url(./fonts/Rajdhani/Rajdhani-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

Here I added a `Rajdhani` font.

Now, we can use our font in css classes like this.

```css
.title{
    font-family: Rajdhani, serif;
    color: #0004;
}
```

### Adding Google fonts

If you like to use google fonts (api) instead of local fonts, you can add it like this.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rajdhani:wght@300;500&display=swap');
```

Similarly, you can also add it inside the `index.html` file using `link` tag.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rajdhani:wght@300;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

(originally posted at https://reactgo.com/add-fonts-to-react-app/)

Comment: Fantastic answer thank you. One thing that caught me is that I used quotes inside url specifier. I used url('./src/fonts/blah.ttf') which did not work. It needed to be url(./src/fonts/blah.ttf). I know it caught me out!

Answer (score 20):

you should see this tutorial: https://scotch.io/@micwanyoike/how-to-add-fonts-to-a-react-project

```
import WebFont from 'webfontloader';

WebFont.load({
  google: {
    families: ['Titillium Web:300,400,700', 'sans-serif']
  }
});
```

I just tried this method and I can say that it works very well ;)

Comment: This is a very nice spot! The only thing I wonder is wherein the browser are these fonts in the network panel, "Fonts" filter

Answer (score 16):

In your CSS file, such as App.css in a create-react-app, add a fontface import. For example:

```css
@fontface {
  font-family: 'Bungee Inline', cursive;
  src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Inline')
}
```

Then simply add the font to the DOM element within the same css file.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Bungee Inline', cursive;
}
```

Comment: It's @font-face if you wanted to do that and it's not necessary with Google's Font API.

Comment: But what if you _want_ to define your fonts in a css file, because that's where they belong? But you still want to leverage Google's hosting? Isn't it necessary then, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 8):

Another option to all of the good answers here is the npm package `react-google-font-loader`, found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-font-loader).

The usage is simple:

```
import GoogleFontLoader from 'react-google-font-loader';

// Somewhere in your React tree:

<GoogleFontLoader
    fonts={[
        {
            font: 'Bungee Inline',
            weights: [400],
        },
    ]}
/>
```

Then you can just use the family name in your CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Bungee Inline', cursive;
}
```

---

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of the `react-google-font-loader` package.

Answer (score 7):

I can see there are various different ways to include google fonts in react app. Let's explore the most preferred and optimum way.

### @import vs link

The two options that google font provides are using `link` and `@import`. So now the question directs toward decision in between `@import` and `link`. There is already a Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7199364/13833218) regarding this comparison and here is a reference from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7199377/13833218)

> `<link>` is preferred in all cases over `@import`, because the latter
> blocks parallel downloads, meaning that the browser will wait for the
> imported file to finish downloading before it starts downloading the
> rest of the content.

So, it's most preferable to use the `link` tag that google font provides

### How to use link and why in a react app?

I have seen few answers giving this method as a solution but I want to make it more clear why it is most preferable.

After using `create-react-app` to initialize the project, you can see a comment in the `index.html` file inside the `public` folder as below.

> You can add **webfonts**, meta tags, or analytics to this file. The build step will place the bundled scripts into the  tag.

So you can simply include the `link` tag that google font provides in the `head` section of the above file.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Inline" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then you can use it in the CSS file and import in JSX

```
font-family: 'Bungee Inline', cursive;
```

Comment: This is the best answer ^^ Was really helpful to make my page load faster

Answer (score 7):

Edit index.css

```js
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue. Turns out I was using `"` instead of `'`.

use `@import url('within single quotes');` like this

not `@import url("within double quotes");` like this

Answer (score 6):

In case someone needs it, you can use [@fontsource.](https://fontsource.org/) They have all of the Google Fonts and seems easier than most of the solutions here.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone looking for a solution with (.less) try below. Open your main or common less file and use like below.

```
@import (css) url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700');

body{
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I added the @import and the @font-face in my css file and it worked.[image]

Comment: you don't need both for google fonts, just `@import` should suffice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48057801/google-font-import-font-face#48057885

Answer (score 3):

Add link tag in index.html on root directory inside public folder.

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Inline"  rel="stylesheet"/>`

then use it in any css file.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new folder fonts in your src folder.
2. Download the google fonts locally and place them inside the fonts folder.
3. Open your index.css file and include the font by referencing the path.

   ```
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Roboto';
      src: local('Roboto'), url(./fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
    }
   ```

now you can use font link this

```
.firstname{
    font-family: Roboto, serif;
    color: #0004;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you Can write code in index.css file then check this work to component show this style text.
[this code I try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjrwg.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Helmet>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
      </Helmet>
      {/* Your other components */}
    </div>
  );
}


enter code here
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It *could* be the self-closing tag of link at the end, try:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Inline" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

and in your main.css file try:

```
body,div {
  font-family: 'Bungee Inline', cursive;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In some cases your font resource maybe somewhere in your project directory.
So you can load it like this using SCSS

```
 $list: (
      "Black",
      "BlackItalic",
      "Bold",
      "BoldItalic",
      "Italic",
      "Light",
      "LightItalic",
      "Medium",
      "MediumItalic",
      "Regular",
      "Thin",
      "ThinItalic"
    );
    
    @mixin setRobotoFonts {
      @each $var in $list {
        @font-face {
          font-family: "Roboto-#{$var}";
          src: url("../fonts/Roboto-#{$var}.ttf") format("ttf");
        }
      }
    }
@include setRobotoFonts();
```