# How do I use Google Fonts in React JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-font-api

I would like to use Google Fonts in React. I am using

```
import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans';
```

in App.js and

```
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', cursive;
```

in the component.css and I am getting a failed to compile error.

Comment: your question is already answerd here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769551/how-to-use-google-fonts-in-react-js/47733243#47733243

Comment: Duplicate post you can check answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769551/how-to-use-google-fonts-in-react-js/47733243#47733243

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you CAN'T import files from URL. You have to host it in local (grab the entire file), or include it in your page's header as you'd do with another "basic" stylesheet.

## Edit

Use the `@import` syntax in your `component.css`.

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans');`

Dylan

Answer (score 0):

go to `component.css`

**for local font :**

```
@font-face {
    src: url('./fonts/Report-Bold.ttf')  format('ttf');
}
```

**for google font:**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald&display=swap');
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for this answer. To improve it, you should wrap your code samples in code fences, for better readability. Have a nice day !