# Google Font @import + @font-face?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to import fonts with Google Fonts with @import and @font-face, in my CSS. I used to only use @font-face with downloaded fonts, but since it takes time to load, I preferred to use the Google Fonts method.

I didn't wanted the "bold" version of Roboto as the "bold" font in my website, so I used @font-face. However, I'm not sure of the way to use it. Is this correct to use @import and @font-face like this?

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,500i');

@font-face
{
    font-family: Roboto;
    src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400");
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500");
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: italic;
    src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400i");
}

@font-face
{
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    src: url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500i");
}
```

I've the feeling I'm importing the fonts twice... but it doesn't even work! (The page displays the default browser font)

Thank you for reading and taking time to help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use like this in your stylesheet

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,500i');
h2{
font-family:Roboto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I precise what font-weight the title should use?

Comment: @Ivaalo just add the weight in the selector. `h2 {font-family:Roboto; font-weight: 500; }`

Comment: Nevermind, I think I get it! I should use `font-weight: 400` in my body and `font-weight: 500` for my bold sections, right? [Late answer: Thank you!]

Comment: Yep, that's how you should do it :)

Answer (score 2):

@font-face make sense when you loading font from files on your server. If you importing from google, use only import and write right properties to elements you want.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,500,500i');

h2 {
   font-family:Roboto;
   font-weight: 500;
}
```