# How to use google fonts in manually created React app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader, webpack-file-loader, google-fonts

I created React app manually (not create-react-app) one by one such as `index.js`, `App.js`, `index.css`, `components folder` etc because I am using React app as a separate app in the Django project.
And in order to use google fonts, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769551/how-to-use-google-fonts-in-react-js).
But when I write `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans')` in the `index.css`, it is giving me this error.

```
ERROR in ./src/index.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans');
| 
 @ ./src/index.js 4:0-21

webpack 5.15.0 compiled with 1 error in 999 ms
```

I think this error is related to `webpack.config.js` and it seems I need to add some rules in the module section related to `css-loader`, `file-loader`, or something else, but I am not sure how to write.
This is just my thought, I have no idea why this is happening.

> webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env" : {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

How to solve this issue? (This issue has happened when I tried to use `react-toastify` also. So I removed it and used another alternative package.) How to use fonts in the non `create-react-app` based project?

Comment: I think you should add a link tag like this inside index.html file instead of using import in css file and install the css-loader. I always use google font like this. https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2#quickstart_guides

Comment: Is this solution for React project?

Comment: Yes, I used this solution on my react projects

Comment: Just remember to change the font-family inside index.css too. It will work when you add the link tags (get from https://fonts.google.com/) into index.html and change to font-family inside index.css to the correct font.

I just change the font to  on JosefinSans this https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-forked-t9s09?file=/public/index.html , you can check it out

Comment: Once I add any code in index.css file, then it is giving me same error. Should I install css-loader?

Comment: If you just get the same error, I think you should add then.

To add css-loader, just follow this https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#getting-started

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.