# react google fonts implementation

Tags: reactjs, google-fonts

I am trying to use a google font in my component, and I made a separate sheet for that component(which is a page)
so now the font is not working although I implemented the following steps:

1. imported the link from here:https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Great+Vibes

and put it in the head of the html file mainly in the react project

and the component has a separate sheet (css sheet) which is linked successfully too and all styles are working

what else could be missing, I tried the steps in here:[How to use Google fonts in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769551/how-to-use-google-fonts-in-react-js)

and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the font into css directly like:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Great+Vibes&display=swap');
```

And define css property on selector you want to use like:

```
font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you paste google fonts link in the  tag of your public/index.html ?
I think [this blog](https://blog.greenroots.info/3-quick-ways-to-add-fonts-to-your-react-app) should help you.

For me, to be sure to have fonts in my app, I choose the @font-face CSS rule by downloading fonts and put it in src/fonts and use @font-face in your src/index.css file or src/App.css file.